# Problems testing services created with maven-scr-plugin when using pax-exam

Tags: java, maven, osgi, pax-exam, maven-scr-plugin

I've set up a very simple "HelloWorld" service to demonstrate my problem.  It uses the maven-scr-plugin to generate a service descriptor and has a pax-exam unit test.  But when I try to run 'mvn clean test' it blocks for a while before giving me this error:

```
 org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.tracker.ServiceLookupException: gave up waiting for service com.liveops.examples.osgi.helloworld.HelloWorldService
```

If I run 'mvn -DskipTests=true package' and then run 'mvn test' (without clean)
it works.  The difference seems to be the addition of this line in my META-INF/M
ANIFEST.MF file:

```
 Service-Component: OSGI-INF/com.liveops.examples.osgi.helloworld.internal.HelloImpl.xml
```

Does anyone know if there is a way to make sure this line is added earlier in the build process so that 'mvn clean test' will pass?  Or is there something else I might be doing wrong?

---

For reference, here is the pom.xml, the service, and the unit test.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.liveops.examples</groupId>
    <artifactId>HelloWorldService</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <packaging>bundle</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ops4j.pax.exam</groupId>
            <artifactId>pax-exam</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
             <groupId>org.ops4j.pax.exam</groupId>
             <artifactId>pax-exam-container-native</artifactId>
             <version>3.3.0</version>
             <scope>test</scope>
         </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ops4j.pax.exam</groupId>
            <artifactId>pax-exam-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ops4j.pax.url</groupId>
            <artifactId>pax-url-aether</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ops4j.pax.exam</groupId>
            <artifactId>pax-exam-link-mvn</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.felix.framework</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>     
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.felix.scr.annotations</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <namespace>com.liveops.examples.osgi.helloworld</namespace>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <!--
                 | the following instructions build a simple set of public/private classes into an OSGi bundle
                -->
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.7</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>                
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.name}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                        <Bundle-Version>${project.version}</Bundle-Version>
                        <!-- Bundle-Activator>${namespace}.internal.HelloActivator</Bundle-Activator -->
                        <!--
                         | assume public classes are in the top package, and private classes are under ".internal"
                        -->
                        <Export-Package>!${namespace}.internal.*,${namespace}.*;version="${project.version}"</Export-Package>
                        <Private-Package>${namespace}.internal.*</Private-Package>
                        <!--
                         | each module can override these defaults in their osgi.bnd file
     -->
                        <!--_include>-osgi.bnd</_include-->
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>   
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-manifest</id>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>manifest</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>          
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-scr-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <supportedProjectTypes>
                        <supportedProjectType>jar</supportedProjectType>
                        <supportedProjectType>bundle</supportedProjectType>
                        <supportedProjectType>war</supportedProjectType>
                    </supportedProjectTypes>
                    <generateAccessors>true</generateAccessors>
                    <strictMode>true</strictMode>
                    <specVersion>1.1</specVersion>
                    <outputDirectory>target/classes</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-scr-scrdescriptor</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>scr</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

HelloWorld Implementation class

```
package com.liveops.examples.osgi.helloworld.internal;

import com.liveops.examples.osgi.helloworld.HelloWorldService;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Service;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Component;


@Component
@Service(HelloWorldService.class)
public class HelloImpl implements HelloWorldService
{  
    public String helloWorld(String personalization)
    {
        return "Hello " + personalization + "!";
    }
}
```

The unit test

```
package com.liveops.examples.osgi.helloworld.internal;

import com.liveops.examples.osgi.helloworld.HelloWorldService;
import junit.framework.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import org.ops4j.pax.exam.Option;
import org.ops4j.pax.exam.Configuration;
import org.ops4j.pax.exam.junit.PaxExam;
import org.ops4j.pax.exam.util.PathUtils;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import static org.ops4j.pax.exam.CoreOptions.*;

@RunWith(PaxExam.class)
public class HelloImplTest
{
    @Inject
    HelloWorldService hws;

    @Configuration

    public static Option[] configuration() throws Exception{
            return options(
                    systemProperty("org.ops4j.pax.logging.DefaultServiceLog.level").value("WARN"),
                    mavenBundle("org.apache.felix", "org.apache.felix.scr", "1.6.2"),
                    bundle("reference:file:" + PathUtils.getBaseDir() + "/target/classes"),
                           junitBundles());
    }

    @Test
    public void testInjection()
    {
        Assert.assertNotNull(hws);
    }

    @Test
    public void testHelloWorld() throws Exception
    {
        Assert.assertNotNull(hws);
        Assert.assertEquals("Hello UnitTest!", hws.helloWorld("UnitTest"));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the ProbeBuilder to enhance your tested bundle:

```
    @ProbeBuilder
public TestProbeBuilder probeConfiguration(TestProbeBuilder probe) {
    probe.setHeader("Service-Component", "OSGI-INF/com.liveops.examples.osgi.helloworld.internal.HelloImpl.xml");
    return probe;
}
```

This most likely is all that's missing.

EDIT:

just in case you're trying to use pax-exam in the same bundle you need to take certain actions in your configuration method:

```
streamBundle(bundle()
.add(SomceClass.class).add("OSGI-INF/com.liveops.examples.osgi.helloworld.internal.HelloImpl.xml", new File("src/main/resources/OSGI-INF/com.liveops.examples.osgi.helloworld.internal.HelloImpl.xml")
.toURL())
.set("Service-Component", "OSGI-INF/com.liveops.examples.osgi.helloworld.internal.HelloImpl.xml")
.build()).start()
```

a complete sample can be found at [here](https://github.com/ANierbeck/Camel-Pax-Exam-Demo/blob/master/route-control/src/test/java/de/nierbeck/camel/exam/demo/control/route/KarafRoutingTest.java#L142)

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this doesn't seem to work.  Apparently `@ProbeBuilder` is deprecated and when I try this method I get this error:


`ERROR: PAXEXAM-PROBE-c57393ab-7878-4dd3-b533-cbbfb90411d4 (18): Component descriptor entry 'OSGI-INF/com.liveops.examples.osgi.helloworld.internal.HelloImpl.xml' not found`

Comment: This is surely not deprecated, did you add this method to your testclass? Take a look at one of my samples: https://github.com/ANierbeck/Camel-Pax-Exam-Demo/blob/master/route-control/src/test/java/de/nierbeck/camel/exam/demo/control/route/KarafRoutingTest.java#L168

Comment: `org.ops4j.pax.exam.junit.ProbeBuilder` is deprecated and has been superseded by `org.ops4j.pax.exam.ProbeBuilder`.

Comment: @hwellmann, @achim-nierbeck - Ahh, thank you for clarifying. My mistake, I was trying to use `junit.ProbeBuilder`.  Still getting the file not found error, however.

Comment: @peterc might very well be that it's not generated yet? Do you use pax-exam tests instead of unit tests? They are ususally for itests.

Comment: @AchimNierbeck This example doesn't show it but my goal was to use pax-exam to inject mock services in the unit test phase.  I am also planning to use it for integration tests but that can be done from a different maven project so shouldn't have any of the issues I'm running into here.

Comment: @peterc This sample doesn't show how to use mockups but it's used in the unit test phase, so you need to make sure you take all your classes and resources of your project in a custom bundle built with a streamBuilder as shown in my sample and in the code above.

Comment: Thanks @AchimNierbeck.  I'll use that as a template for these tests then.

Answer (score 0):

I may have a fix for this, though it seems a bit in-elegant.  I can explicitly add the *Service-Component* to the *maven-bundle-plugin* section of the pom file.

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.7</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>                
        <configuration>
            <instructions>
                <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.name}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                <Bundle-Version>${project.version}</Bundle-Version>
                <Export-Package>!${namespace}.internal.*,${namespace}.*;version="${project.version}"</Export-Package>
                <Private-Package>${namespace}.internal.*</Private-Package>

                <!--Explicitly add the components no that they can be found in the test phase -->
                <Service-Component>OSGI-INF/com.liveops.examples.osgi.helloworld.internal.HelloImpl.xml</Service-Component>
            </instructions>
        </configuration>   
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>generate-manifest</id>
                <phase>process-classes</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>manifest</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>          
    </plugin>
```

Please let me know if anyone can think of a better way.

Answer (score 0):

The Maven SCR Plugin only generates the service component descriptors but it does not include them in the manifest automatically.

So there's nothing inelegant about including a `<Service-Component>` instruction in the Maven Bundle Plugin configuration, that's just the [documented usage](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-scr-plugin/apache-felix-maven-scr-plugin-use.html).

Since the manifest header is missing, SCR does not register any services on behalf of your bundle, and that's why Pax Exam can't find the required service.

Comment: I appreciate your answer.  I think this is the way I will go but the document you link to does say that the `<Service-Component>` will be created when you use both `maven-scr-plugin` and `maven-bundle-plugin` so "you don't have to configure this yourself".  And it does, in fact, generate this entry in the MANIFEST.MF file.  It just doest it too late for the test phase and, as you said, the service isn't registered so pax-exam can't find it.